# How do I resample data in R?

Tags: r, r-caret, resampling

I am conducting an elastic net regression. I have my training and test data. I need to resample my training data.

I have tried:

```
set.seed(5627)
> down_inside <- train(state ~ ., data = train.data,
+                      method = "treebag",
+                      nbagg = 50,
+                      metric = "ROC",
+                      trControl = control)
Something is wrong; all the logLoss metric values are missing:
    logLoss         AUC          prAUC        Accuracy  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1     NA's   :1     NA's   :1
```

As you can see, I am getting NA's. My response factor variable (state) is 3 level.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput(train.data)`?

Comment: Hi Quinten, I managed to get past this part - it appeared to be a minor error in one of the columns. However, I am now getting this error:  down_inside <- train(state ~ ., data = train.data,method = "treebag",nbagg = 50,metric = "ROC",trControl = control)
Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  The metric "ROC" was not in the result set. logLoss will be used instead.
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Comment: Hi @luke laban, Great you pasted that part. It would be helpful if you can share a small sample of your data so we can reproduce your problem and help you better.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Hi @quinten, sorry for the delayed response. I'm still working on this but keep getting the error. My data was originally 1's and 0's but I changed to 1's and 2's thinking that 0 values would maybe have something to do with the ROC curve been left out of the results. Please find the data in the next response box.

Comment: structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("one", "three", "two"), class = "factor"), B = c(1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), C = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), D = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), E = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), F = c(1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2), G = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1), H = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), I = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), J = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Comment: I am trying to subsample during resampling following section 11.2 on here: https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html#subsampling-during-resampling.        I am trying to try different methods of resampling (down, up and ROSE) and then if I'm correct, compare the ROC to see which is the best method. I'm 6 months into using R so please correct me if I get anything wrong.